# I can't install ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-1.8.7

I want to install ruby 1.8.7 and uninstall ruby 1.9.2 from main. Please don't suggest rvm as I do have that. But ruby 1.9.2p0 is sticked to my system.. I tried `sudo apt-get remove ruby`, it removes ruby, but when i run `ruby -v` it shows ruby 1.9.2p0 is there...
I want to install ruby 1.8.7 for redmine.

PLease suggest how to remove  1.9.2 and install 1.8.7

Comment: what is the output of `which ruby` after uninstalling ruby

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rvm exists for this very reason - you don't need to remove ruby 1.9.2 to add 1.8.7.  Check out the [rvm cheat sheet](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm) and look under the "Install Ruby" and "Selecting Ruby for Work" headings.

Namely, you should be able to run `rvm install 1.8.7` then `rvm use 1.8.7` when you want to switch to it.  Just run `rvm use 1.9.2` when you want to switch back to Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:?

```
apt-get install ruby1.8
```

And then tried running:

```
$ ruby1.8
```

Comment: yes, but i am not root user, so i need to use sudo apt-get..:(

Comment: @user1571530 ok,? so use sudo?